# What exactly do Officer Gary's words really mean?

Tags: meaning

In ***[Practical Magic](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120791/)***, Officer Gary say these words to Sally.

> I thought I came here to **bring in the bad guy** because, generally,
>   that's what I do.

What does **bring in the bad guy** actually mean? Also please explain the whole sentence also.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! We expect people to do a little research before asking a question. In this case, you could look up terms like **bad guy** in a good dictionary https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bad_guy. If you are still confused, please update your question to explain what you don't understand, and include details (including links) to your research. You should be able to find out what **bring in the bad guys** means. Regarding the whole sentence, we really need more context, for example a summary of the story at this point of the preceding lines in the dialogue.

Comment: I haven't watched it, but based on the synopsis on Wikipedia, it sounds like Gary, a police officer, was meant to arrest Sally ("bring in the bad guy") because this is what police officers usually do ("generally, that's what I do"). However, instead of arresting the bad guy, Gary has fallen in love with her instead, and this is why he says "he thought" because he realizes he had been mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restated in simpler English and reverse order:
Usually, I bring bad people to the police station.
I thought today I would do that.
(Implied: Today I did not bring a bad person to the police station)

Note: "bring in" can be a phrasal verb with many different meanings. It is not used that way here. Bring=take somebody somewhere(in this case). In=where he took that person. It is implied by his job title that where he takes bad people is into the police station.